# Changing Style of objects inside controltemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, controltemplate

I made a new control which contains a rectangle in it with and some visual states.

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="banda">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF47B215" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="{Binding Background, ElementName=Border}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF86B072" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="purple" StrokeThickness="5"  Stroke="{Binding Background, ElementName=Border}"/>
                        </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        </Style>
```

This control is used many times in my application page and I'd like the rectangle to have different colour value every time it's used, for example when I press a button, the rectangle changes colour.

I don't have idea how to change the property of the rectangle inside the c# code though. Can someone help me with the formatting?

Comment: So you just want to have the ability to set the Default background color in each instance you use it on?

Comment: Yes, i'd like to change the background of the rectangle for every istance of the control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sweat, just build that functionality into the template by binding the `Background` of it like so;

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="banda">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"/>
           <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF47B215" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="{Binding Background, ElementName=Border}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF86B072" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{Binding Background, ElementName=Border}"/>
                        </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
     </Style>
```

So this way, the default color will be Purple (as seen in the `Setter` declaration) and you can change it on the fly like;

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource banda}" Content="Blah" Background="Orange"/>
```

However; it is normally recommended you don't attach to many state changes to a single object. For example if you load your template into Expression blend you'll and you look at your States Panel while editing your template, you'll see a triangle exclamation mark icon warning you that its not advised to base too many states around a single object in your template. Most of the time its fine though and will work as is. Also you had `Stroke` & `StrokeThickness` applied to a `Border` which doesn't have those Dependency Properties, so in the example I fixed that as well to `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush`. Oh and you're probably also going to find how you have your properties so inter-relationship bound its going to cause you troubles. Ditch the things like;

```
                         <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="{Binding Background, ElementName=Border}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
```

and instead just bind it to the `Background` property via `{TemplateBinding Background}` instead. I would suggest looking at some of the default control templates for Buttons and comparing to learn more of how they're used.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Without doubt i'm making a lot of mistakes and things could be done better! I'll be sure to check out your solution after my exams! thanks again :)